# What does 死锤 mean?

Tags: translation

What does 死锤 mean? I get that it's probably some type of weaponry, but I want a clearer translation. Below is the whole sentence.

这个时候就是众人与其死锤的时候了。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say "我要跟你死锤了", it means you will fight with someone untill either you or the other die, that's where the 死 comes from, and 锤 means a solid battle.

This is a spoken word, usually you will meet the literary equivalent one 决一死战.

Comment: Is it a newly coined phrase? Does it originate from video games?

Comment: It's a localism slang, being popular on the Internet in recent years.

Answer (score 1):

死 + fight action = fight until one of the party dies (metaphorically or literally).

Depending on the context, it could be implying "no retreat" or "no mercy" or both, but in most cases it's focusing on the determination i.e. "no retreat" aspect.

Examples:

- 死战 (as in 决一死战): fight until death; fight without retreat.
- 死磕 (common word Northern/Beijing dialect): bug/harass/fight someone until the request is answered.
- 死锤 (network language): "hammer" (harshly argue, criticize, condemn) someone until they surrender/confess.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose 死锤 evolved from 实锤，which to describe someone or something got a evidence to proof truth or false.

So , 死锤 isn’t meaning death hammer,but just like struggle to argue or fight for the results .